# problem storing image as blob to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, blob

First of all i am very new with database systems. i am trying to store an image on my db (only for testing purposes) however I cannot do. There is a problem in the code I use. Can you please tell me what is wrong with the following code?

```
Create DIRECTORY temp as 'c:\temp';

DECLARE
  src_lob  BFILE := BFILENAME('temp', 'IMAGE.png');
  dest_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES(2, EMPTY_BLOB())
     RETURNING doc INTO dest_lob;

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_lob, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_lob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_lob,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_lob) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_lob);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

When I try to run it, I have the following error: ORA-00911: invalid character

What is wrong here?

Thannks in advance.

Comment: @cagcowboy I don't know, ORA-00911: invalid character is the only error message shown

Answer (score 1):

Never done it so I'm not certain, but I think the DIRECTORY has to be on the server, not the client.

(You may be running SQL*Plus on the server I guess)

Comment: server and client are the sane machine (my pc)